# Android GLSurfaceView OpenGL ES with linear-gradient background?

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, glsurfaceview, linear-gradients

with this code, I can clear the background and add a color:

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);    
gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.35f, 1.0f);
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

How can i change this to have a linear-gradient Background? e.g. White color at the top and blue color at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method to clear to a gradient, but I'd just draw a colored quad instead of clearing the color:

```
void drawFrame() {
   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   //draw screen aligned quad with color gradient 
   //    (top two vertices white, bottom two blue)
   drawGradientQuad();

   glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //no need to clear color

   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   //draw rest of scene
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything about GL_QUADS?

Comment: @user1405328 Your comment is a statement, not a question, and I don't know what you're talking about. If you're confused about something please be specific.

Comment: Sorry. The drawGradientQuad(); is that a real function, or is that only an example? I found a website. I think, it is the same what you said. But this doesn't work.
 http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/164345-Gradient-background

Comment: @user1405328 No, it's not a real function, it's just pseudocode. I assumed that you would know how to draw simple shapes on your own. If you don't know how, I'm sure you can find plenty of tutorials and resources for drawing triangles and quads.